# jquery get values from table cells

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I need to get the value of a textbox inside the 5th column in my table and show that value in an alert.

The textboxes are having names as : T[1] , T[2] , T[3] ..........T[30]

```
 $('#MyTable tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function(index) {

       var TextBoxValue = $("input[type=text][name^=T]").eq(index).val();

    });
```

My table has : 10colums and 30rows

But its skipping one row , and showing the odd row Textbox values in the alert box.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your markup looks like or where you were going with the `.eq(index)` piece, but try this out:

```
 $('#MyTable tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function(index) {

    var TextBoxValue = $("input[type=text][name^=T]", this).val();

    console.log(TextBoxValue);
});
```

The most important change I made was adding context to the selector, "`, this`". I also removed the "`.eq(index)`" part.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/CpNZV/

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but what was the problem in .eq(index) . why wasn't it working?

Comment: *Technically*, there was nothing wrong with it (hence no error message), but the usage made no sense.  According to the jQuery docs, the `eq()` function is used to "reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index." So, say you're in your 7th iteration of the `each()` loop, your original selector would look for the 7th instance of `$("input[type=text][name^=T]")` in a single cell.